# Evernote Android SDK library throws java.lang.VerifyError under R8

Tags: android, evernote, android-r8

Facing notorious `java.lang.VerifyError`. Initially problem showed up in Fabric. Was able to reproduce (with identical stacktrace) once set `minifyEnabled true` for debug build.

```java
Caused by java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TEvernoteHttpClient: void com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TEvernoteHttpClient.cancel() failed to verify: void com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TEvernoteHttpClient.cancel(): [0x6] 'this' argument 'Reference: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase' not instance of 'Reference: org.apache.http.client.methods.AbstractExecutionAwareRequest'
 void com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TEvernoteHttpClient.flush() failed to verify: void com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TEvernoteHttpClient.flush(): [0x7F] 'this' argument 'Reference: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' not instance of 'Reference: org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient' (declaration of 'com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TEvernoteHttpClient' appears in base.apk)
       at com.evernote.client.android.ClientFactory.createNoteStoreClient + 85(ClientFactory.java:85)
```

I see that typically `java.lang.VerifyError` issues are recognized as related to difference between code to compile and run against.

This is not the case since code runs just fine when minification is disabled.

The way I see this can be helped is making another rule, but I am failing to understand which classes need to be kept from this error details.

We are already doing

```java
-keep class com.evernote.** { *; }
-keep interface com.evernote.** { *; }

-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep interface org.apache.http.** { *; }
```

... and those classes don't get modified in any way. I've checked it using `-printusage ./full-r8-config.txt` instruction and checking the output. Classes mentioned in error details do not show up there.

**UPDATE 1 day later:**
Really strange thing going on here.
So far I have a verified backup plan: switching back to proguard fixes issue.

But in case if I want to stay with R8, here comes:

- using `-dontshrink`, `-dontoptimize` and `-dontobfuscate` (all three at once) does no impact;
- forcing specific apache.http version dependency does no impact;
- I've checked mapping: neither Evernore SDK, nor Apache http classes don't get obfuscated;
- issue pertains when app executed on api22 device (emulator, actually);
- I was able to debug code once I had `-dontobfuscate` set. All goes well until Evernote's `ClientFactory#createUserStoreClient` decides to instantiate `TEvernoteHttpClient` - the moment program execution touches latter class's constructor - exception thrown.

It looks like it is all good to go, but this verifier fails.

**Later update:**

Issue filed as a bug for R8: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139268389. Please feel free to star it if facing similar situation (all code is in place but VerifyError is thrown)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write below proguard rules.

```
-dontwarn com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TAndroidTransport
-dontwarn com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.DiskBackedByteStore
-dontwarn com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.ByteStore 
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
```